# Joint CDF from piecewise marginal

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution

> Let X be a positive r.v. with density $f$ with $f(x) > 0~ \forall~ x>0$. Let Y be a r.v. that is equal to X if $X \leq 5$ and $X^3$ if $X > 5$.

I am self-studying probability, and I'm quite stuck on this question. I want to find the joint CDF of (X, Y). The way I'm thinking is:

$$
\begin{align}F_{(X, Y)} &= P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)\\
&= P(Y \leq y| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(Y \leq y| X > 5)P(X> 5)\\
&= P(X \leq y| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X^3 \leq y| X > 5)P(X> 5)
\end{align}
$$

Not quite sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y>0$,

\begin{align}F_{(X, Y)} &= P(X \leq x, Y \leq \color{red}y)\\
&= P(X \leq x, Y \leq y| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X \leq x, Y \leq y| X > 5)P(X> 5)\\
&= P(X \leq x, X \leq y| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X \leq x, X^3 \leq y| X > 5)P(X> 5) \\
&= P(X \leq \min(x, y)| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X \leq \min(x,  y^\frac13)| X > 5)P(X> 5) \\
\end{align}

Now, everything is in terms of $X$, hopefully you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your way:

\begin{align}F_{X, Y}(x,y) &= P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)\\
&= P(X \leq x, X \leq y| X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X \leq x,X^3 \leq y| X > 5)P(X> 5)\\
&= P(X \leq min(x,y) | X \leq 5)P(X\leq 5) + P(X \leq min(x,\sqrt[3]{y})|X>5)P(X \gt 5)\\
&= P(X\leq min(x,y,5)) + P(5 < X\leq min(x,\sqrt[3]{y}))\\
&= F_X(min(x,y,5)) + F_X(min(x,\sqrt[3]{y})) - F_X(5)
\end{align}

Here note that, the second probability can be expanded only if $x<5$ and $y < 125$, o/w it'll be zero.