# Represent $P(x,y)$ with $P(x)$ and $P(y)$, what are the pre-conditions we require?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function

$x$, $y$ are two random variables. Given density functions $P(x)$ and $P(y)$, can we represent the joint probability density function $P(x,y)$? if not, what are the key conditions we require to derive $P(x,y)$?

I am not familiar with probability theory, forgive me if I asked a dumb question and it is highly appreciated if anyone could give some clues or solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joint CDF from piecewise marginal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366511/joint-cdf-from-piecewise-marginal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not possible to get the joint probability density from marginal densities without additional assumptions on the dependence structure.

A simple sufficient assumption is that $x$ and $y$ are independent random variables. Then $P(x, y) = P(x) \cdot P(y)$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_independent_variables).

[Sklar's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SklarsTheorem.html)  (also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar%27s_theorem)) makes clear that more generally assumptions are needed that fully describe the dependence structure between $x$ and $y$. Such assumptions can take many different forms. One example of such assumptions is given in the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/366511/353799) provided in the comment by Xi'an.

Comment: Sklar's theorem states that there exists a map, called a copula, from the generalized infverses of the marginal CDFs whose image is the joint CDF. A corollary of this is that that if the marginal CDFs are continuous then the copula is unique.